# Hitting RESTful API through firefox

Tags: api, firefox, rest, httprequest, restful-authentication

I am trying out a RESTful API that has OAuth. I have the API base Url, the API key and the Secret.
Is it possible for me to hit that API through firefox (need to be able to choose Request Method and supply OAuth info)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the Poster extension? I believe it has authorization support.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/

http://code.google.com/p/poster-extension/issues/detail?id=55

Comment: For those interested in a Chrome version, check this one out: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/faceofpmfclkengnkgkgjkcibdbhemoc

Comment: hmm the oauth interface is not too well labeled... I am guess this left box is key and the right is secret?

Comment: Use the Headers tab to add the Authorization header. See the example in second link.

Comment: Bob, thanks for the upvote. If this is what you were looking for, please mark this as the answer.

Comment: This doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Look at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/. It surely has OAuth support. The UI is also excellent.

Comment: As of 2021-11-12, it says right in the description "Some functions are still missing (OAuth & OAuth 2.0 authentication)."  Maybe this was written before the plugin was re-written for the new version of Firefox plugings.

Answer (score 0):

[HttpRequester](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/httprequester/) is really easy and fast to use. Its shortcut is Alt+Ctrl+P

Comment: This doesn't seem to exist anymore.